# $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ continuous function. Which of the following sets can not be image of $(0,1]$ under $f$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ continuous function. Which of the following sets can not be image of $(0,1]$ under $f$?

> > A. $\{0\}$.
> >
> > B. $(0,1)$.
> >
> > C.$[0,1)$.
> >
> > D.$[0,1]$.

**My effort:** Continuous image of connected set connected. $(0,1]$ is connected and remove $1$ from the set left the set connected...but removing any point from $(0,1)$ make it disconnected.....I am not sure though

Comment: What are your ideas?

Comment: I think Ans is one of A or B.

Comment: **A.** $f(x)=0$ is continuous. @yiokk

Comment: Ah, I misread the "not". A,C and D. can be the image and I think B. is impossible.

Comment: This is a question of Tifr 15 phd entrance test...and it says only one option is correct??

Comment: Reply to user133281's comment, please! @yiokk or you question will be closed for not showing any efforts towards the problem.

Comment: Continuous image of connected set connected. $(0,1]$ is connected and remove $1$ from the set left the set connected...bot removing any point from $(0,1)$ make it disconnected.....I am not sure though.

Comment: It's "B". Otherwise: The maximum of $f(x)$ on $[0,1]$ would have to be $1$ and it would have to occur at $x=0$. The minimum would have to be $0$; but where would this have to occur? Your connectedness argument also works.

Comment: @DavidMitra How is it with the connectedness? If you remove a point from the domain, the image might stay unchanged?

Comment: @PeterFranek Ah, I overlooked that...

Answer (score 11):

If $f\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is continuous, then the image of any compact set is compact. Especially, the image of $[0,1]$ is a compact set $C$. Then the image of $(0,1]$ is either $C$ or $C\setminus\{y\}$ for $x=f(0)$. The set $(0,1)$ is not of this form, hence cannot be the image of $(0,1]$.

For A, C, D one readily finds specific functions: $f(x)=0$, $f(x)=1-x$, $f(x)=|2x-1|$.

Comment: You said " Then the image of $(0,1] $ is either $C$ or $C\setminus\{y\}$ " How
??

Answer (score 8):

One can easily find continuous functions with image such as in A,C or D, so if only one option is correct, it must be B.

To prove that B is impossible, you can argue as follows. Find, in the preimage, sequences $x_n$ and $y_n$ so that $f(x_n)\to 1$ and $f(y_n)\to 0$. Neither $1$ nor $0$ is in the image, so neither $x_n$ nor $y_n$ contains a subsequence convergent in $(0,1]$. But in $(0,1]$ the only chance for having a sequence that doesn't contain a convergent subsequence in $(0,1]$ is a sequence converging to $0$ (in $\mathbb{R}$). So, $x_n\to 0$ and $y_n\to 0$, hence $0=\lim f(x_n)=\lim f(y_n)=1$ which is a contradiction.

David Mitra offers a simpler argument in the comments above.

However, $(0,1)$ *is* a continuous image of $(0,1]$; for example $f(x)=(1-x)(\frac{1}{2}\sin(\frac{1}{x}))+\frac{1}{2}$ maps $(0,1]$ continuousy onto $(0,1)$. (But $f$ can not be continuously extended to $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$)

Comment: Can you provide me an example of **D** please? Just curious. :)

Comment: Think about the graph.. start with identity on $(0,\epsilon)$ and then go up and down..

Comment: @SwapnilTripathi Just take straight line segments from $(0,1/2)$ to $(1/2,1)$ to $(3/4,0)$ to $(1,1/2)$.

Comment: Oh, that was simple. Thank you. @DavidMitra

Comment: @PeterFranek- Why are you contradicting your own answer in the last line? Are you saying the question is incorrect?

Comment: @algebraically_speaking I'm not doing that. There is a continuous map $(0,1]$ onto $(0,1)$ but it cannot be extended to $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @PeterFranek- Oh alright. Thank you!