# Which set cannot be the image of $(0,1]$ under a continuous function and why .

Tags: general-topology, continuity

> Let  $f :\mathbb R \rightarrow\mathbb R$ be  continuous  function . Then  which  cannot  be  the  image  of $(0,1]$ ?
>
> A. $\{0\}$
>
> B. $(0,1)$
>
> C. $[0,1)$
>
> D. $[0,1]$

Now  A.  is  the  constant  map. C. is  the  map  $f(x)=1-x$.
Little  confusion  about  B.  and D. If  it  is  that  $(0,1)$  is  embedded  in  $(0,1]$ so  B. cannot  be  the  answer  then  similarly   $(0,1]$  is  embedded  in  $[0,1]$  so  D.  is  also  not  the  answer . All  answers  wrong   is  not  a  possibility.  What  did  I  miss  here?

Comment: I don't understand why you think $(0,1)$ can be the continuous image of $(0,1]$.

Comment: The function $f(x)=1-x$ does not map the real line to $[0,1)$.  Also, the question supposes that the image equals whatever set they specify.  Mapping $f$ to a subset doesn't count.  $f$ has to be a surjection onto its image.

Comment: @lulu: It maps $(0,1]$ to $[0,1)$...

Comment: @MikeMiller.  Ah! misread the question.  Thanks!

Comment: $f(x)=1-x$ does  map  $(0,1]$  to $[0,1)$  . Draw  the   graph  and  see.  And  yes  it  has  to  be  surjective. @lulu

Comment: @user118494 You are correct, I misread the question.

Comment: @MikeMiller What about the function $(1-x)\sin(1/x)$?  That maps $(0,1]$ to $(-1, 1)$, and can clearly be modified to map into $(0,1)$.

Comment: @Donkey_2009: I meant to say I don't understand the reasoning. I like that function. You should post an answer.

Comment: @Donkey_2009 But is that a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: D is easy: just make the function to be zero until $1/2$ and then increase it linearly to $1$ at $1$.

Comment: B is impossible, The image of $[1/n,1]$ is compact $\subset(0,1)$, so the only way to get an open image when $n\to\infty$ is that $\liminf_{x\to 0}f(x)=0$ and $\limsup_{x\to 0}f(x)=1$, but then the limit at zero does not exist.

Comment: BTW possible duplicate http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1067606/f-mathbb-r-to-mathbb-r-continuous-function-which-of-the-following-sets-can-n

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option $A$ $\rightarrow $ $\mathcal constant  \ \ function$

Option $C$ $\rightarrow$  $f(x)=1-x$

Option $D$ $\rightarrow$  $f(x)=|2x-1|$

The impossible  one  is  option $B$.  Here  are  two  different  explanations **:**

$1)$If possible , let us assume that $f((0,1])=(0,1).$ So, In $(0,1)$ we can find two sequences(**Since this is not compact**) that do  not converge in $(0,1)$. Say $$w_n\rightarrow 0$$  and  $$z_n\rightarrow 1$$.
Since , $(0,1)$ is the image of $(0,1]$ under $f$ , we can write $$w_n=f(x_n)$$ and $$z_n=f(y_n).$$ For  two  sequences  $x_n$  and  $y_n$ in  $(0,1].$ If both  $x_n$ and $y_n$   have  convergent subsequences  in  $(0,1]$  then  by continuity  of  $f$ , $f(x_n)=w_n$ and $f(y_n)=z_n$ both have convergent  subsequences  and  eventually  converge  in  $f((0,1]=(0,1)$ , which is not the case. But in $(0,1]$ , the only chance of a sequence not having a convergent sub sequence is that , it converges to $0$ .   *This  is  how  we  ensure  that :*

By **Bolzano-Weierstrass  Theorem** , we know that *Every bounded sequence has a convergent sub sequence*(**In the completion of the sub space of $\mathbb R$  in  consideration**). So every sequence in $(0,1)$ has a convergent sub sequence  in $\bar{(0,1]}=[0,1].$ The only limit point of $(0,1)$ that is not **in** $(0,1]$  is $0$ . Thus , both  $x_n$ and $y_n$ must have $0$ as their limit  in order not to converge **in** $(0,1].$

But  then $$\lim_n x_n=0=\lim_n y_n\\i.e.\ \ \lim_n f(x_n)=f(0)=\lim_n f(y_n)\\ i.e.\ \ 0=f(0)=1$$  which  is  totally  absurd . So, $$f((0,1])\neq (0,1)$$.
 Proved.

$2)$  We can write $$[0,1]=\{0\}\cup (0,1].$$  NOw for  compactness , $$f([0,1])=C$$ for some *connected,compact* set $C$. Now , $$C=f([0,1])=f(\{0\})\cup f((0,1]).$$ Dependeng  on whether $f$ is injective or not , $$f((0,1])=C\backslash \{y\}\\or,\ \ f((0,1])=C.$$ So, for $B)$ to be true , we need $$(0,1)=C\backslash \{y\} \ or\ C$$  but $(0,1)$ is not of that form . So , we have arrived at a contradiction again. So $B)$  is  not  true. **Proved.**

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to see that B is impossible is that if $f:R\to R$ is continuous then $f$ restricted to the domain $[0,1]$ is continuous.  The continuous image of a compact space is compact. Case B would require that $S=\{f(0)\}\cup f (0,1]=\{f(0)\}\cup (0,1)$ is compact. But $S\in\{(0,1),[0,1),(0,1]\}$ so $S$ is not compact.

Answer (score 1):

B. $(1+\cos^2 (1/x))/(2+x)$ will do this. (Oops, this is wrong because $f$ was to be continuous on $\mathbb R ;$ see below.)

D. $4(1-x^2)$ will do it.

---

It was pointed out to me that these functions need to continuous on $\mathbb R.$ Then B. is impossible: We have $f([0,1]) = f(\{0\})\cup (0,1).$ But $f([0,1])$ is compact, and $f(\{0\})\cup (0,1)$ is either $(0,1),[0,1),$ or $(0,1]$ - none of which is compact.

Comment: About B: the  function must be continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. About D: I get the image of $(0,1]$ to be $[0,4)$.

Comment: Thank you, didn't see that.

Comment: Sorry  but  this  does  not  make  any  sense  to  me. We  needed  to  contradict the possibilities  of $f((0,1])=(0,1)$ being  true. Where  did  $f([0,1])$  come  from  here  and  what  kind of  explanation  of  what  is  this $?$ Totally  messed up !

Comment: It's not messed up, but your attitude is.